# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 50), found shape=(None, 1, 512)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multiclass-classification

Learning to use bert-base-cased and a classification model... the code for the model is the following:

```
def mao_func(input_ids, masks, labels):
return {'input_ids':input_ids, 'attention_mask':masks}, labels

dataset = dataset.map(mao_func)

BATCH_SIZE = 32
dataset = dataset.shuffle(100000).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

split = .8
ds_len = len(list(dataset))

train = dataset.take(round(ds_len * split))
val = dataset.skip(round(ds_len * split))

from transformers import TFAutoModel
bert = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
```

Model: "tf_bert_model"

---

## Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #

bert (TFBertMainLayer)      multiple                  108310272

=================================================================
Total params: 108,310,272
Trainable params: 108,310,272
Non-trainable params: 0

then the NN builduing:

```
input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(50,), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')
mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(50,), name='attention_mask', dtype='int32')

embeddings = bert(input_ids, attention_mask=mask)[0]

X = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(embeddings)
X = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(X)
X = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(X)
X = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(X)
X = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(X)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax',name='outputs')(X)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids, mask], outputs=y)

model.layers[2].trainable = False
```

the model.summary is:

```
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_ids (InputLayer)         [(None, 50)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 attention_mask (InputLayer)    [(None, 50)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 tf_bert_model (TFBertModel)    TFBaseModelOutputWi  108310272   ['input_ids[0][0]',              
                                thPoolingAndCrossAt               'attention_mask[0][0]']         
                                tentions(last_hidde                                               
                                n_state=(None, 50,                                                
                                768),                                                             
                                 pooler_output=(Non                                               
                                e, 768),                                                          
                                 past_key_values=No                                               
                                ne, hidden_states=N                                               
                                one, attentions=Non                                               
                                e, cross_attentions                                               
                                =None)                                                            
                                                                                                  
 global_max_pooling1d (GlobalMa  (None, 768)         0           ['tf_bert_model[0][0]']          
 xPooling1D)                                                                                      
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization (BatchNorm  (None, 768)         3072        ['global_max_pooling1d[0][0]']   
 alization)                                                                                       
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 128)          98432       ['batch_normalization[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 dropout_37 (Dropout)           (None, 128)          0           ['dense[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)                (None, 32)           4128        ['dropout_37[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 outputs (Dense)                (None, 3)            99          ['dense_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 108,416,003
Trainable params: 104,195
Non-trainable params: 108,311,808
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

finally the model fitting is

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01)
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
acc = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

model.compile(optimizer,loss=loss, metrics=[acc])

history = model.fit(
    train,
    validation_data = val,
     epochs=140
)
```

with execution error in line 7 -> the model.fit(...):

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 50), found shape=(None, 1, 512)
```

Can any one be so kind of helping me on what I did wrong and why... thanks:)

update: here is the git with the codes https://github.com/CharlieArreola/OnlinePosts

Answer (score 4):

It seems, that your shape of the train data doen't match the expected input shape of your input layer.
You can check your shape of the train data with `train.shape()`

You input layer `Input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(50,), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')` expects train data with **50** columns, but you most likely have **512** if we look at your error.
So to fix this, you could simply change your input shape.

```
Input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(512,), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')
```

If you split your x and y in your dataset you can make it more flexible with:

```
Input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(train_x.shape[0],), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')
```

**Also don't forget, that you have to do this change to all of your input layers!**

Comment: Hi Fabian! so I tried just changing the 50 col to 512 without splitting, still receiving an error "Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 512), found shape=(None, 1, 512)" ... btw train.shape was not available in my tf so I did an iteration dataset_length = [i for i,_ in enumerate(train)][-1] + 1... the length is 3902.

Comment: mhh strange.. but without your dateset I can't reproduce and just guess.
Well a quick fix/try would be to include the 1 also in your input layers `shape=(1,512)`. Let me know if this works. Else you might have to let mme know what dataset you are using ;)
Another thing worth trying would be using a Flatten()-Layer before your input which should give you an Flatten Layer with an Output of (None,512)

Comment: Just upload my 2 notebook and dataset here https://github.com/CharlieArreola/OnlinePosts (the input pipeline is where I generate the input_ids, masks annd labels

Comment: Will have a look tomorrow  and update my answer :)

Comment: Hi:) very friendly reminder for help over here ... sorry&thanks